# boost circular_buffer or heap sorting performance

Tags: c++, sorting, boost, heap, circular-buffer

I need to sort object that arrive to a process X before treating them.
Object are sorted given to a time-stamp - a 64 bit number.
When object are timed out(a few milli) and sorted, the process X start to look at them.
 
Most of the time the object arrive sorted, between 3% and 5% the objects are out of order.

So i need a structure that allow me to:
  - insert quickly elements
  - remove quickly timed out elements

What should be the best to sort them, in term of performance?
I started to implement with boost::circular_buffer.
If boost::heap is better for this, which boost::heap should i use? Because there are a few(fibonacci, binomial, priority queue...)
I am using boost 1_49 but i can use a newer version also.

With circular buffer i insert most of the elements at the beginning of the buffer. But it can be O(n) in some case.
But to take timed out element it is O(1)

Answer (score 2):

You will need to measure but I would guess that a `std::priority_queue<T>` has a fair chance to be most efficient. Using any of the other heaps won't do you much good because you don't really need the additional operations (changing the priority of an element) but being able to use these operations increases the overhead quite significantly.

Especially when the size of `T` is a bit bigger but even if it is just an `int`, you may want to use a *d*-heap with *d == 8*: although this results in more comparisons it reduces the number of times an object is moved.